# Find out if react-bootstrap Navbar is collapsed

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

First, the nomenclature here is somewhat vague. I will be explicitly using "collapse" to refer to `react-bootstrap`'s behavior of collapsing the `Navbar` on smaller viewport widths, and "expand" in reference to toggling a collapsed menu into and out of view.

My goal is to create a navigation bar that, while collapsed (mobile), uses the whole `Navbar` as a toggle to expand the menu. On wider displays (not collapsed) clicking the `Navbar` should have no action. For this, I need to know if the `Navbar` has collapsed. (Note that `Navbar`'s `expanded` prop doesn't cut it here.)

The obvious solution is to modify behavior based on viewport width. However, I'd like not to copy bootstrap's breakpoint widths, but rather refer to the actual state of the `Navbar`. That would allow for using `Navbar`'s `expand` prop to change breakpoint setting, etc. Is it possible to access this information in a reasonable manner?

Thanks, all!